# Is there a REST based ORM?

Tags: javascript, ajax, orm, rest

I've been looking at JavaScriptMVC, and I'm pretty interested in the idea.  I'm wondering, though, if there are any ORM solutions for such an architecture.  It seems like you will end up having to write two data access layers, one server side to fetch items from the database and one on the client side to retrieve items via AJAX.

My question is, are there any existing (preferably open source) solutions that would let me define a model (XML or class definition) and generate a REST api for me to access my data.  I've been looking at DataMapper while I'm thinking about this, and it would be great if create a model, and instead of calling `Person.all(:age.gt => 30)` like I would in ruby I could just query `/Person/All/?filter="age>30"` (properly escaped of course) and get back an object serialized to XML without having to write the controller myself.

Is there anything out there like this? Does this seem like an intelligent way to go about framing a javascript based app?

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC, the REST metaphor lives in the controllers, not the data model. Which makes sense, since it is the controllers that expose the REST interface to the outside world. I would imagine the same is true for JavaScriptMVC. There are ways to automate the creation of the controllers, such as code generation.  The method of calling the REST interface is very similar to your example.

Comment: With .NET 4.0 you can consider to use entity framework 4 and WCF data service 4 together. Take a look at this video from TechEd http://www.msteched.com/2010/NorthAmerica/DEV303 (I am not 100% sure if this is the video as I have watched a couple of them, but you can browser around and look for one you interested in).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research, I think I've found my answer.  Using CouchDB I can have all of the application logic running in the clients browser and use the built in REST api to persist the data to the server.  This way, I could even manage the model in the client side javascript.